# SQLite: How to read array, which is saved as string, and work with array?

Tags: sqlite

For some reason my `.db` file has a `table1` with a `Column1`, which data are stored as `TEXT`:

```
Column1
'[1,   2,   0.5]'
'[50,  8.5, 30]'
'[12,  14,  0.5]'
'[5,   45,  25]'
'[0.2, 10,  25]'
```

These data are in TEXT format, although they look like Array.

I want to use the data as array.

To be exactly: I want to DELETE the rows, which second item is less than 15.
The desired result should be:

```
Column1
'[5,   45,  25]'
```

I tried a lot of methods on my own, but none of them worked. One of my many tries looks like: (I admit I have absolutely no idea how to do this task.)

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE Column1 <= 15;
```

Could anybody please help me out? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqlite doesn't have a real array type. However, it *does* have support for working with JSON (Assuming your sqlite instance was compiled with the [JSON1](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) extension, of course). And your sample values happen to be valid JSON arrays.

That gives us something to work with:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE json_extract(column1, '$[1]') < 15;
```